# The Image of sphere under the map $f: (x,y,z) \to (x^2,y^2,z^2,\sqrt{2}yz, \sqrt{2}zx, \sqrt{2}xy)$ and $\mathbb{R}P^2$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm going to take a course about diferentiable manifolds next semester and I'm preparing for it by solving some of the problems from the book *An Introduction to Differential Manifolds* by D. Barden and C. Thomas. My understanding of the material is very rudimentary, I'm just memorizing the definitions and the theorems so far without reading their proofs. So, please post only the solutions that use the basic definitions and theorems.

Show that the image of $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ under the map $f: (x,y,z) \to (x^2,y^2,z^2,\sqrt{2}yz, \sqrt{2}zx, \sqrt{2}xy)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$. How does it relate to $\mathbb{R}P^2$?

Introducing charts on the $\mathrm{Im}(f)\mid_{S^2}$ seems not trivial. However, I have made an observation that I think handles the first part.

$$Df=\begin{bmatrix}
2x & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 2y & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2z\\
0 & \sqrt{2}z & \sqrt{2}y\\
\sqrt{2}z & 0 & \sqrt{2}x\\
\sqrt{2}y & \sqrt{2}x & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

has constant rank $2$ over $S$ because at least one of the coordinates $x,y,z$ must be non-zero and then I can find a $2\times 2$ sub-matrix with non-zero determinant. If necessary, I can first exchange two rows to create this sub-matrix.

I think this shows that the tangent to $\mathrm{Im}(f)\mid_{S^2}$ is always a plane, so it's a $2$-dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^6$. But I don't know how to make my reasoning rigorous.

I think that $\mathrm{Im}(f)$ is diffeomoprhic to $\mathbb{R}P^2$. Well, at least they have the same dimension. Plus, the image of $f$ is given by a homogeneous polynomial. I don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, $\text{Im}(f)$ and $\mathbb{R}P^n$ are diffeomorphic.

Recall that we have a quotient map $p:S^n \to \mathbb{R}P^n$ which identifies antipodal points. Note that $f$ is constant over the fibers of $p$ so it pass to the quotient, that is, there exists a unique differentiable function $\tilde{f} : \mathbb{R}P^n \to \mathbb{R}^6$ such that $\tilde{f}\circ p = f$.

Note that $\tilde{f}$ is injective so its corestriction $g := \tilde{f}|^{\text{Im}(f)}:\mathbb{R}P^n \to \text{Im}(f)$ is a bijection. Now, because $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is compact and manifolds are Hausdorff spaces we have that $g$ is a homeomorphism and then by the Inverse Function Theorem it is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks. Two questions: is the quotient map smooth? (why?) And doesn't the inverse function theorem give us local diffeomorphism? I don't understand the last part. + how can I make my answer to the first part rigorous? Is it even right?

Comment: Yes, the quotient map is differentiable by definition because we endow the quotient space with the unique differential structure such that the quotient map is a local diffeomorphism. (Of course, not every quotient of a manifold is a manifold but there are results which says that under very general conditions the quotient is a manifold.)

Comment: For the second question, well... you have to endow the image of $f$ with a suitable differential structure. For example you can prove that it is a regular (or embedded) submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$ but this follows from the fact that $f$ is a (topological) embedding and it has maximum constant rank.

Comment: Both results are basic and you can find they in every introductory book

Comment: Hmm. I'm confused. If we want to prove that $\mathrm{Im}(f)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$, we must first endow it with a differential structure? If we have already defined a differential structure on $\mathrm{Im}(f)$, why do we need $f$ then? I'm not following the logic. :|

Comment: The fact that the polynomials are homogeneous is linked to algebraic geometric issues. You can write $\text{Im}(f)$ as the set of zeros of a (finite) set of polynomials for example.

Comment: Please don't mention algebraic geometry. I'll panic. But I think we are still discussing this within the world of differential manifolds. In this context, I do not understand how the fact that the rank of the differential is constant proves that it is a submanifold in the codomain. I mean it makes sense to me intuitively and that's why I wrote it down, but I don't see how it follows from the theory.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I can not say that $g$ is a diffeomorphism if its codomain does not have a differential structure. But we have a definition of regular/embedded submanifold as the image of a topological embedding that has maximum constant rank and a result following this definition give us the differential structure of such a submanifold. Let me look for a reference.

Comment: See  Proposition 5.2 in John M. Lee, Introduction to smooth manifolds, Springer, 2013, second edition.